# PFUser Current User gets Erased after Login

Tags: ios, parse-platform

PFUser currentUser works fine on iOS after logging in, but whenever I deploy a new app or crash the app manually, I have to re-sign it, which is not only annoying but not how Parse CurrentUser system works. Anybody know why? I am checking it in the completion block, and it displays correctly there...

Comment: Well. First. Add the code on how you sign someone up or log them in.